# (NoMethodError) undefined method `t' for main:Object in Aptana

Tags: jquery, aptana

I'm getting the following on Aptana Scripting Console after installing jQuery bundle for Aptana 3.0

```
    [2012-03-18 14:39:27] An error occurred while executing C:\Users\Administrator\Aptana Rubles\javascript-jquery.ruble\bundle.rb: (NoMethodError) undefined method `t' for main:Object
    [2012-03-18 14:39:27] An error occurred while executing C:\Users\Administrator\Aptana Rubles\javascript-jquery.ruble\bundle.rb: (NoMethodError) undefined method `t' for main:Object
```

After that,Whenever I start Aptana 3.0, I'm getting following error mesg.

```
    [2012-03-18 13:26:35] An error occurred while executing /home/zagg/Documents/Aptana Rubles/javascript-jquery.ruble/bundle.rb: (NoMethodError) undefined method `t' for main:Object
    [2012-03-18 13:26:35] An error occurred while executing /home/zagg/Documents/Aptana Rubles/javascript-jquery.ruble/commands/documentation_for_word.rb: (NoMethodError) undefined method `t' for main:Object
    [2012-03-18 13:26:36] An error occurred while executing /home/zagg/Documents/Aptana Rubles/javascript-jquery.ruble/snippets/snippets.rb: (NoMethodError) undefined method `t' for main:Object
```

has anyone else encountered this error? 
can someone help me out. Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been solved, you only need to update Aptana to the lastest version.

https://github.com/aptana/studio3/issues/27